# \midsloppy and \lettrine do not play nice

Tags: spacing, lettrine

My issue has to do with the word spacing of the small caps the follows the lettrine. I'd like it to flow and wrap with the rest of the text, but it doesn't.

Here is a MWE:

[image: MWE render]

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\midsloppy
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\lettrine{E}{xample text that is quite long but not} too long, to demonstrate the weird word spacing that occurs when using the small caps feature.
\end{document}
```

Notice the extremely different spacing between "not" and "too".

If I remove `\midsloppy`, then it looks better, but its not really a fix because the rest my document gets broken with overflowing words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `\lettrine` is boxed, so the spaces in it are not flexible.

```latex
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\longlettrine}[3]{%
  \lettrine{#1}{#2} {\LettrineTextFont #3}%
}

\midsloppy
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\longlettrine{E}{xample}{text that is quite long but not} too long, to demonstrate
the weird word spacing that occurs when using the small caps feature.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same, but with the original syntax: we change `\usebox{\L@tbox}` into `\unhbox\L@tbox`, so the spaces in the box regain their flexibility.

```latex
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lettrine}
 {\usebox{\L@tbox}}
 {\unhbox\L@tbox}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\midsloppy
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\lettrine{E}{xample text that is quite long but not} too long, to demonstrate
the weird word spacing that occurs when using the small caps feature.

\end{document}
```